# Send Specific data to specific emails using Laravel8

Tags: sql, laravel-8, query-builder

I Have the following form of data :

Table1

```
-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
| id_contrat     |  numero_contrat   | contrat        |id_filiale      |
-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
|1               |  20210001         |   xxxxxx       |2               |       
|2               |  20210002         |   yyyyyy       |1               |
|3               |  20210003         |   zzzzzz       |2               |
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
Table 2 :
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id_filiale     |  adm_emails                                               |     
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1               |  ["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]                  |  
|2               |  ["email3@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]                                 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please, if you can help me with a Query, I've been stuck since yesterday, so I'm building a program that sends emails to users, so I'm stuck in the fact that for example the `contracts 1 and 3` must be sent to `["email3@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]` and the `contracts 2`  must be sent to  `["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]` .

I'm really stuck to how to do that using query builder in Laravel.

I should choose witch contracts to send to which emails according to the `id_filiale` key.

I did a join with the two tables but how can I choose a specific data to a send to a specific emails.

If you have any idea please help

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it wil only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: why ?  I store them as an array